# Create a system to edit texts of a website

Tags: text, web, content-management-system, edit

Hello I'm making a website and I want that an user can edit some of the texts content in the website, clicking a button "Save" and the changes are permanent.
I suppose I have to put all the text in a database instead of keeping it in html code, but this will slow down the website loading performance.
Is there a library to easily achieve this functionality? Pheraps changing html code instead of acting on the database.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the file content and load it into a form in a textarea or [WYSIWYG](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wysiwyg/info) and after submitting the form, put the changed data back into the file. The codes for loading and saving data, depends on programming language. check the documentation for opening and saving the file in PHP here.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php